# filling the remaining width of a containing element

Tags: css

I have an element that is 50% width, and inside that element are two more elements, one of the elements is a fixed 100px wide, and I want the other element to take up the rest of the containing element, but cant work it out.

The element I want to take up the remaining space in the container has this css

```
#header_search {float:left; width:50%}
```

Obviously 50% with isnt right. But not sure what it should be.

https://jsfiddle.net/mux7e7b4/

How is that done?

Comment: Are you trying to get the search box fill the rest of the nav container?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you need to have the search box as a sibling of the "header_logo_cont".

Answer (score 0):

Give the element you want to take up most of the width the following CSS,

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

Here's how it would look in your example ([updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/orvn/mux7e7b4/1/))

Note that the input element has a border around it which sets off calculations, so `box-sizing:border-box;` is necessary to include the border within the total element width.

- Calc() is not recognized in IE8 and below.
- It also doesn't work on some older Android phones that haven't been updated.
- Best practice is to use some kind of a fallback for graceful degradation, depending on your specific use-case.

Comment: How browser compatible is that? It sounds perfect for what I want.